# iad cocos2d - iphone development

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, iad

i'm developing a physics game with cocos2d framework. I added iAd to it. When the ad appears,  the scenary elements get disoriented (sprites jump). i've notice FPS decrease a lot and i don't know what to do to solve the problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've certainly noticed cases of mixing UIKit and Cocos2D in developing our own games with [Get Set Games](http://www.getsetgames.com).  While I have never mixed iAd with what we are doing however we have used Mobclix.   Could be there is something specific about the way you are using iAd which is slowing down things for you although without looking at some of your code I can't be certain.    You should also do a search through the [Cocos2D forums](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/).  Try posting your question there as well.

Answer (score 0):

May be this [topic](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/7521) gets you some ideas.